# Leaflet JS Plugin

Tags: leaflet, plugins

I'm having trouble getting a simple java script plugin to work on my script. I'm trying to get the measure tool to work. The little toolbar pops up but it doesn't do anything. When I run it I get the error... Uncaught TypeError: L.control.selectLayers is not a function. How do I fix this?

Leaflet Heat Map

```
<!-- Start css file links -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet/1.0.0-beta.2/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/L.Control.Locate.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Leaflet.Coordinates-0.1.5.css"/>
<!-- End css file links -->

<!-- Start JavaScript calls -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet/1.0.0-beta.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/2.0.0-beta.8/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/L.Control.Locate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Leaflet.Coordinates-0.1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/leaflet-heat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/TileLayer.WMTS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/L.MeasureAreaControl.js"></script>
<!-- End JavaScript calls -->

<!-- Start GeoJSON Data Load -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="data/heatpoints1.js"></script>
<!-- End GeoJSON Data Load -->

<style>
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map{ width: 1200px; height: 700px; position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; } 
</style>

</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.geocoder/2.0.2/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.geocoder/2.0.2/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js"></script>

<!-- display map -->
<div id="map"></div>

<script>

//  Instantiate Map
var map = L.map('map').setView([38.80690, -77.26940], 8);

//  Basemaaps
//  OpenStreetMap
var openstreetmap = new L.TileLayer('http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg', {
    subdomains: '1234',
    format: 'image/png',
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 19,
    opacity: 1,
    attribution: 'Map tiles &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> and contributors <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'
}).addTo(map);

//  USGS Topo
var usgstopo = new L.TileLayer.WMTS('http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS?', {
    format: 'image/png',
    minZoom: 5,
    maxZoom: 15,
    opacity: 1,
    attribution: 'Map tiles &copy; <a href="http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/maps/maps-and-map-layers" target="_blank">Esri</a>'
    });

//  Overlays
//  TIGERWeb - Counties
var counties = new L.TileLayer.WMS('http://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/services/TIGERweb/tigerWMS_Current/MapServer/WmsServer?', {
    format: 'image/png',
    layers: 'Counties,States',
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 15,
    opacity: 1,
    transparent: true,
    zIndex: 1000,
    attribution: 'Map tiles courtesy of <a href="http://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/tigerwebmain/TIGERweb_wms.html">US Census Bureau</a>'
});

//  The National Map - Roads (Interstate and US)
var majorroads = new L.TileLayer.WMS('http://services.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/transportation/MapServer/WMSServer', {
    format: 'image/png',
    layers: '6,7,15,16',
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 16,
    opacity: 1,
    transparent: true,
    zIndex: 1000,
    attribution: 'Map tiles courtesy of <a href="http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/services/" target="_blank">US Geological Survey</a>'
});

//  Start Heat Map
var golf = L.heatLayer(golfcoursePoints,{
    radius: 25,
    blur: 25, 
    maxZoom: 17
//  gradient: {
//      0.1: '#ffffb2',
//      0.3: '#fd8d3c',
//      0.8: '#fd8d3c', 
//      0.9: '#f03b20',
//      1.0: '#bd0026'
//  }
});
//  End Heat Map

var basemaps = {
    "OpenStreetMap": openstreetmap,
    "Topo": usgstopo
    };

var overlayMaps = {
    "Boundaries - State and County": counties,
    "Major Roads": majorroads,
    "Maryland Golf Courses": golf
    };

var layerControl = L.control.layers(basemaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: true}).addTo(map);

var arcgisOnline = L.esri.Geocoding.arcgisOnlineProvider();

var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch({
    providers: [arcgisOnline]
    }).addTo(map);

var results = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

    searchControl.on('results', function(data){
    results.clearLayers();
    for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
    }
    });

//Measure Tool
var control2 = new L.Control.measureAreaControl(basemaps, overlayMaps)
control2.addTo(map);

// Display mouse coordinates
var mouseControl = new L.control.coordinates({
    position:"bottomleft",
    decimals:6,
    decimalSeperator:",",
    labelTemplateLat:"Latitude: {y}",
    labelTemplateLng:"Longitude: {x}"
    });

// Display scale control
var scaleControl = new L.control.scale({
    position: 'bottomleft'
    });

var control = L.control.selectLayers(basemaps, overlayMaps)
control.addTo(map)

    map.addControl(mouseControl);
    map.addControl(scaleControl);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you have is an unhandled exception where the JavaScript object of a type is commended to behave as another type.  Given that this is all your written code, the Leaflet API doesn't have a `selectLayer` member therefore `selectLayer`s is *undefined*.  An undefined object cannot execute as a function.  Inspecting `L.control.selectLayers` should return *undefined*.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use [Leaflet.selectLayers plugin](https://github.com/vogdb/SelectLayersControl), you need to download the [corresponding JavaScript file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vogdb/SelectLayersControl/master/dist/leaflet.select-layers.min.js), and add it through a script tag to your page in order for the JS engine to know what `L.control.selectLayers` is. As said by IvanSanchez, it is not part of the core Leaflet API.

Assuming you have placed the JS file in your `scripts` subfolder, like the other plugins you use:

```html
<script src="scripts/leaflet.select-layers.min.js"></script>
```

Not sure why you instantiate `L.control.layers` then try to instantiate `L.control.selectLayers`…

Answer (score 2):

```
var control = L.control.selectLayers(basemaps, overlayMaps)
```

That is wrong, you probably meant to write:

```
var control = L.control.layers(basemaps, overlayMaps)
```

I suggest you should [double-check the Leaflet API documentation about `L.Control.Layers`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers).